# Tail bounds on random series in Hilbert space

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, asymptotics

Tail bounds on random series in Hilbert space

Let $X_n$, $n \in \mathbb {N}$, be independent $\pm 1$ symmetric random variables, and $a_n$,
$n \in \mathbb {N}$, be a sequence in a Hilbert space $H$ such that
$\sum_n \|a_n\|^2 < \infty$, say $= 1$. Set $Z = \| \sum_n a_n X_n \|$ so that
$E(Z^2) = \sum_n \|a_n\|^2  = 1$. Since $E(Z) \leq 1$, it is of interest to bound the
probability $ P( Z > 1 + t)$, $t >0$. What would be a (sharp, exponential?) tail estimate in terms of the coefficients $a_n$, and in which range of $t >0$?

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.g. [Theorem 3.5](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176988477), whereby
$$P(Z\ge t)\le2e^{-t^2/2}\tag{1}$$
for all real $t\ge0$.

The coefficient $1/2$ in the exponent is of course sharp, in view of the standard central limit theorem (in $\mathbb R$), whereby $\sum_{j=1}^nX_j/\sqrt n$ converges to a standard normal random variable in distribution.

---

$\newcommand\si\sigma$Write
$$Z=\Big\|\sum_n a_n X_n\Big\|=\sup_{\|x\|\le1}\sum_n X_n\langle a_n,x\rangle $$
and let
$$\si^2:=4\sup_{\|x\|\le1}\sum_n \langle a_n,x\rangle^2
\le4\sum_n \|a_n\|^2=4. $$
Then, by Talagrand's concentration inequality for product measures (see e.g. [Section 2.2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec13.pdf)),
$$P(|Z-m_Z|\ge t)\le4\exp\Big\{-\frac{t^2}{4\si^2}\Big\}$$
for all real $t\ge0$, where $m_Z$ is a median of $Z$ and hence
$$P(|Z-EZ|\ge t)\le P(|Z-m_Z|\ge t-\sqrt{8\pi}\,\si)
\le4\exp\Big\{-\frac{(t-\sqrt{8\pi}\,\si)^2}{4\si^2}\Big\}\tag{2}$$
for all real $t\ge\sqrt{8\pi}\,\si$.
The bound (2) will be better than (1) if $\si^2<1/8$ and $t$ is large enough.

Comment: I was told that there is somewhere an inequality involving the coefficients a_n by the (smaller) quantity sup \sum_n \langle y, a_n \rangle^2, where the sup is over all y in H with norm one?

Comment: @Yilmis : They apparently meant something like the now added bound (2).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Yilmis : So, are you now satisfied with the answer?